# How to check Presto card balance without an account using only python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to write a quick script to check the balance of my Presto card (public transit payment card for systems in Ontario, Canada) using python-requests only.

On their website (prestocard.ca), if you click on "Sign In" in the top right corner, it brings up a floating tabbed menu. If you click on the "Without an Account" it allows you to enter your card number and click "Sign In" it then brings you to another page (/dashboard) from which it is easy to scrape the card balance. BUT, I can't figure out how to use python-requests only to provide my card # and to load the dashboard page.

Here's the important/relevant part of the webpage source for the floating tabbed menu:

```
<form action="/api/sitecore/AFMSAuthentication/SignInWithFareMedia" id="sign-in-without-account" method="post">
<div class="form-group signinwithoutaccount13">
<label for="fareMediaId">PRESTO Card Number*</label>
<input type="text" class="signin-input form-control signin-tabs_input" id="fareMediaId" name="fareMediaId" aria-describedby="frmError" aria-required="true">
<span class="errorMsg" id="frmError"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" class="green-btn signin-modal-signin-btn btn__background--emphasis btn__border--emphasis btn__text--white" id="Numsignin">Sign In</button>
<button type="reset" id="btncancelmodal_wa" data-dismiss="modal" class="green-btn signin-modal-signin-btn btn__background--white btn__border--grey btn__text--black">Cancel</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Seems it should be simple, but I haven't been able to make it work. Maybe because of https... I just don't know enough about POST/GET requests, cookies, and/or SSL to figure it out. I tried something along these lines with no success (`<Response [200]>`):

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.prestocard.ca/api/sitecore/AFMSAuthentication/SignInWithFareMedia'
payload = {}
payload['fareMediaId'] = # MY card ID
with requests.Session() as s:
    bob = s.post(url, data=payload)
    bob = s.get('https://www.prestocard.ca/en/dashboard')
print bob.text
```

I found [this](https://github.com/nsalerni/Presto-Card-Balance-Checker/blob/master/prestoCardBalanceCheck.py) github code but it's only for login with an account (so I can't test it), and it uses more python modules than I think is necessary (though I could be wrong). Any help/advice writing a python script that would require only python-requests would be much appreciated.

Comment: response 200 is a success though......

Comment: What's in `bob.text`? Nothing?

Comment: Ha, indeed! I feel pretty silly that after a bunch of changes to the code posted above I hadn't re-tried to check the content of `bob.text`. The code actually work. Thank you @dmitry-polonskiy and @jcvanhamme for your comments/questions. I posted an answer to my own question with a polished code below.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question actually works just fine. The code below has slight improvements: it retrieves the exact Presto card balance as a float from the returned website (as long as you enter your own Presto card ID as a series of numbers without the dashes):

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.prestocard.ca/en/api/sitecore/AFMSAuthentication/SignInWithFareMedia'
with requests.Session() as s:
    prestopage = s.post(url, data={'fareMediaId': 'ENTERYOURPRESTONUMBERHERE'})
    prestopage = s.get('https://www.prestocard.ca/en/dashboard')
print float(prestopage.text.split(r'<span class="rob-cart-amount">$')[1].split(r"</span>")[0])
```